# CFMessagePortInvalidationCallBack has no context info for remote ports

Tags: cocoa, core-foundation

When creating local ports with CFMessagePortCreateLocal you can specify context info (void *).  This is useful for pointing to an Objective-C class instance.  With CFMessagePortCreateRemote you can not specify context info.  If you wish to monitor when a remote port is invalidated via the callback specified with CFMessagePortSetInvalidationCallBack you don't have that info available in the callback.  Is there a work-around besides using a static variable?

I may have an unknown number of remote ports connected to separate processes.

Comment: Your callback gets the `CFMessagePortRef` for the port. You need to create a data structure to track the remote message ports you create and map those to other relevant data. Alternatively, since all `CFType` objects are toll-free bridged to `NSObject` and thus `id`, you might be able to use the associated object API (e.g. `objc_setAssociatedObject()`).

Comment: @KenThomases Please add your objc_setAssociatedObject suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted answer.  It appears to do exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all `CFType` objects are toll-free bridged to `NSObject` and thus `id`, you can use the associated object API (e.g. `objc_setAssociatedObject()`).